# how to store xml to xlsx using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, xlsxwriter

I have data in XML format and want to store in excel file.

XML FILE:

```
<!--some code....-->
  <r id="1">
    <smp id="f9eb9" />
    <data>
      < id="S12345" />
      <cq>41.25</cq>
      <a>
        <c>1</c>
        <t>72.0215</t>
        <f>0.0417169</f>
      </a>
      <a>
        <c>2</c>
        <t>72.0263</t>
        <f>0.04169</f>
      </a>
      <a>
        <c>3</c>
        <t>72.0223</t>
        <f>0.0417146</f>
      </a>
    </data>
  </r>
```

I have already wrote code for it and use BeautifulSoup,but couldn't reach exactly.

```
import sys
import csv
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

# Create a workbook and add a worksheet.
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('/home/randm.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with open("/home/data.xml","r") as f:
contents = f.read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(contents,'xml')
data = []
data3=[]
data2=[]
data1 = []
cols =set()

for item in soup.findAll('r'):
    d = {}
    m=[]
    n=[]
    for cid in item.findAll('c'):
        m.append(cid.text)
        d[cid.name] = m
        #data1=d.popitem()
        data2=cid.findNextSiblings('f')
        data3=(data1[1][-1])
        print data3,data2
```

Now, I want to store data3 and data2 in Excel

Require Output:In Excel format from the above code

```
  c    f
  1    0.0417169
  2    0.04169
  3    0.0417146
```

Does anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Have you gone through the xlsxwriter tutorial on writing to a file? http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial03.html

Comment: I tried it but couldn't retrieve the value in excel. If you have any idea plz share with me.

Comment: Your sample code doesn't have any lines trying to write things to the Excel file as suggested by the tutorial I linked to. You need to use something like `worksheet.write_string(row, col, string[, cell_format])` around where you have your `print` statement. Put `workbook.close()` at the end of your file.

Comment: worksheet.write(row, col + 1, data2)# not working